# Does SystemVerilog Generate support delays?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench, vlsi

I thought of generating clock using `genvar` like below:

```
        reg [7:0]clk;  
      
     genvar i;
        generate
          for (i=0; i < 7; i++) begin
              #1 clk[i]=~clk[i];
            end
        endgenerate
```

I am getting an error:

> error: near "#": syntax error, unexpected '#'

How can we resolve it?  Can I use delays inside `generate` block?

Comment: You can put anything inside a generate block that you can put between `module` and `endmodule`. What you are trying to put inside your generate block would not be legal between `module` and `endmodule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `generate` blocks support delays.  To fix your problem, use a procedural `always` block:

```
reg [7:0] clk;  

genvar i;
generate
    for (i=0; i < 7; i++) begin
        always #1 clk[i]=~clk[i];
    end
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel it isn't necessary to have a generate, you can use the for loop directly in an always block:

```
reg [7:0] clk;
integer i;
always begin
  #1;
  for(i = 0; i < 7; i = i + 1)
    clk[i] = ~clk[i];
end
```

Nevertheless, if all the bits are toggled at the same time, you can simplify it with:

```
always
  #1 clk = ~clk; //..bitwise invert the array
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like OP wanted to have a sequential delay model. In this case the code should look like this:

```
always begin
  for(i = 0; i < 7; i = i + 1)
    #1 clk[i] = ~clk[i];
end
```